# Blender Denoise and Glare nodes

Tags: denoise

I want to add a glare node to my render result but when I do that I can't use the denoise node, I tried to combine them with mix node but then it's only allowing to 50% of each node to take effect on the render.

I tried to save the render after denoise is applied and then open it in a new image node in blender and the connect it to glare node but it doesn't look good, looks a lot darker and I tried all the color spaces on the node and none of them gives the result that I want.

Answer (score 2):

So it was a simple fix, just had to connect the denoise node to glare and then the glare to composite and now the image have a full denoise applied to it and also the glare effect that I wanted.